# Slider range not going to correct position

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm trying to create a custom range slider. Everything works well besides for when you zoom in on the webpage, then reload. When I do that, the range slider (green background) doesn't drag to its correct position.

Here's the relevant code: (In function sliderMove line 30)

```
cursorPosition = ((e.touches && e.touches[0].clientX) || e.clientX) - startPoint.left;

rangePosition = clamp(cursorPosition, _sliderPositions.rangeStart, _sliderPositions.rangeEnd);
cursorPosition = clamp(cursorPosition - cursorRadius, _sliderPositions.cursorStart, _sliderPositions.cursorEnd);
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```js
console.clear();

function RangeSlider( /** DOM Elem */ parentElem) {
  var wrapperElem = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapperElem')[0],
    slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0],
    sliderRange = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderRange')[0],
    sliderCursor = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderCursor')[0],
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

  var sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth,
    cursorRadius = sliderCursor.offsetHeight / 2,
    startPoint,
    currentTarget,
    value = 0,
    _sliderPositions = {},
    borderWidth = 1;

  startPoint = getOrigin(wrapperElem.children[0]);
  sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth;


  function sliderDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
    sliderMove(e);
  }

  function sliderMove(e) {
    var rangePosition = 0;
    var cursorPosition = 0;
    reconfigVars();
    if (typeof e === 'object') {
      cursorPosition = ((e.touches && e.touches[0].clientX) || e.clientX) - startPoint.left;
    } else {
      cursorPosition = pixelToPercent(value, 0, 500) / 100 * sliderDimention;
    }
    //console.log(cursorPosition);

    rangePosition = clamp(cursorPosition, _sliderPositions.rangeStart, _sliderPositions.rangeEnd);
    cursorPosition = clamp(cursorPosition - cursorRadius, _sliderPositions.cursorStart, _sliderPositions.cursorEnd);

    sliderCursor.style.transform = 'translateX(' + cursorPosition + 'px)';
    sliderRange.style.transform = 'scaleX(' + rangePosition + ')';

    if (typeof e === 'object') {
      value = percentToPixel((
        (cursorPosition - _sliderPositions.cursorStart) / (_sliderPositions.currentValue - borderWidth * 2)
      ) * 100, 0, 500);
    }
    output.innerHTML = value;
  }


  function reconfigVars() {
    _sliderPositions.rangeStart = borderWidth * 2;
    _sliderPositions.rangeEnd = sliderDimention - borderWidth * 2
    _sliderPositions.cursorStart = startPoint.left - cursorRadius + borderWidth * 2;
    _sliderPositions.cursorEnd = sliderDimention - borderWidth * 2 - cursorRadius * 2;
    _sliderPositions.currentValue = sliderDimention - borderWidth * 2 - startPoint.left - cursorRadius;
  }

  myButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sliderMove(500);
    value = 500;
  });






  function mouseUpEvents() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
  }
  wrapperElem.addEventListener('mousedown', sliderDown);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEvents);
}



var sliderTest = document.getElementById('sliderTest');
var test = new RangeSlider(sliderTest);







function getOrigin(elm) {
  var box = (elm.getBoundingClientRect) ? elm.getBoundingClientRect() : {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    doc = elm && elm.ownerDocument,
    body = doc.body,
    win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow || window,
    docElem = doc.documentElement || body.parentNode,
    clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0, // border on html or body or both
    clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  return {
    left: box.left + (win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft) - clientLeft,
    top: box.top + (win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop) - clientTop
  };
}

function clamp(val, moreThan, lessThan) {
  if (typeof lessThan === 'undefined') lessThan = 1;
  if (typeof moreThan === 'undefined') moreThan = 0;
  return Math.min(lessThan, Math.max(moreThan, val));
}

function pixelToPercent(pixel, min, max) {
  if (typeof max === 'undefined') return;
  return ((pixel - min) / (max - min)) * 100;
}

function percentToPixel(percent, min, max) {
  if (typeof max === 'undefined') return;
  return ((percent / 100) * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```css
.wrapperElem {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
.slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 62px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.sliderCursor {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.sliderRange {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: left;
}
#output {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperElem">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="sliderRange"></div>
    <div class="sliderCursor"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="output"></div>
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: It would work better if you used `width` instead of `transform`. Transform s what's killing ya. [***See this***](https://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/bwsmv9fp/1/) & see what I mean.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend a more algebraic approach to clipping, and really I'd drop all the fancy css all together. Much of it is still not greatly cross compat and you're going to run into issues with transform in every browser simply due to the nature. Unless you're prepared to build a robust library for dealing with different browsers, it's best sometimes to just stick to the basics. Look at how [`jQueryUI`](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) handles theirs, very simple css with classes helping control the end results.

Comment: @SpYk3HH Thanks! The reason I used `transform` is because, performance is better when using 'transform' over 'width'. Can u show me an example of what you mean in the second comment? Thanks!

Comment: Simply put, your variables aren't interchangeable enough and depending on client touches is still going to leave extreme values to the right, thus causing over extension when someone is "zoomed in". It would be better to make a simple equation with interchangeable variables so you can keep up with such changes in visual transition, such as calculating the `sliderRange`'s width based on percentage of its parent's width. This way you'll never overextend and have an awkward looking slider.

Comment: @SpYk3HH Can you please show me an example?

Comment: If I get a chance this weekend, I'll throw something together and show you what I mean, since I'm horrible at explanations.

Comment: @SpYk3HH Did you have time to figure it out?